# Problem with exec() in PHP

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

Well, i have this program i need to run via either functions however it is located on my dekstop (this ubuntu 11.04).

I moved it to /home/Username, but no dice.

I run

```
$blah = exec('sudo | echo mypassword | /home/server1/program commandhere', $test); 
var_dump($test); 
var_dump($blah); ?>
```

The output is nothing.

I was told if i wanted to run it via sudo i needed to add the Apache user which is www-data to the sudoers list, i added it, but no luck again.
Basically, i've tried A LOT of things, it just wont run. Why?

EDIT:
If i paste that into the terminal it works great, just not with exec,system nor passtrhu.

Comment: Why are you piping the output of `sudo` to `echo`?

Comment: Because when you do sudo program it asks you for the password, you dont type the password before doing sudo.

Comment: the way you're invoking `sudo` there really doesn't work. To test, try this: `sudo | echo mypassword | echo test > /test.txt`. It will show a `Permission denied` error. Make sure you didn't use `sudo` very recently though, as that will cache your credentials and will alter the test results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `echo mypassword | sudo -S` instead.

It also depends on which user has `sudo` privileges. If you want to run this from the `apache` process, you need to give the `apache` user `sudo` privileges as well.

Also, just to clarify, the command should be:

```
echo mypassword | sudo -S /home/server1/program commandhere
```

Comment: Even like so, the program does not execute..or at least nothing is being printed as it should be. And there's quite the data to be printed.

Comment: Sorry, it just doesnt work. The program should print a lot of data, and according to exec it should store every line that was printed in the variable, but nothing is there. So i asume the program never even got executed.

Comment: Then try to debug the problem. Start with running a simple `echo test >/tmp/a.txt` and see if `/tmp/a.txt` contains text. If it does, go further, try to run a command requiring root privileges, such as `echo mypassword | sudo -S umount /test 2>&1 >/tmp/a.txt` and see if this fills the file with text. If it doesn't, then it's a problem with the way you're invoking sudo.

Comment: Also, see *what user is running `sudo`*. It won't be your user. It will be the user under which the PHP process runs. Perhaps `apache` or `httpd`. If that's it, then you need to set a password for this user and allow it `sudo` access.

Comment: When i ran that code i got [sudo] password for nobody: Sorry, try again. A file was created, however it was empty.

Comment: There's your used then: `nobody`. Make sure it has a password and `sudo` privileges.

Comment: Thanks man, you saved me a sh** ton of work to do. It's 6AM here, and if it wasn't for you i would've probably stayed even more trying to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look into your security log. Not sure where this is on Ubuntu, possibly /var/log/secure or /var/log/messages. I'm betting that you find a message there similar to `sudo requires a TTY`, or `sorry, you must have a TTY to run sudo` indicating that `sudo` is configured not to work without a real interactive shell.  That is, `sudo` won't permit you to use it in a script or to be called by an external program.

I recently dealt with this issue myself while trying to bind a Gnome keyboard shortcut to a `sudo` command.

If this is the case, you'll need to comment out the following line in `/etc/sudoers`

```
#Defaults requiretty
```

Comment: Nope, i have env_reset there only. And it just doesnt work...the program is not being executed.